# Android Application and Device Compatibility

Tags: android

I wanna ask guide about android application Compatibility,I am developing an application using Android 2.2-SDK . . .Will this application run on device with 3.1 finely ? Where from I can read like these android Compatibilities ?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test your app on a 3.1 device (or emulator if you don't have access to a device), but generally, yes. It may be windowed or not show in the market you don't specify proper [large screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) in your manifest, though -- read more on the Android developers site: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

Android 3.1 is optimized for Tablets, while your application will run it may not function visually the same due to it being massively scaled up for a tablet sized screen. If you are unsure how it will look then set up the emulator included in the SDK and set it to the screen size/resolution of a tablet and see for yourself.